# WIFI failures: No Functioning DNS available

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, dns, wireless-adapter

WIFI always disconnects, and reports "no internet access". It might connect back after some time. It happens in many different locations: at home, in coffee shops etc. My colleague told me that it might be a problem with WIFI adapter in my laptop. It might be loosely connected and overheating. Or might require replacement. Before I go that way I wanted to get second opinion. Thanks.

**Right after I lost internet connection I got the following from the Chrome Diagnostics:**

```
    SUMMARY
Test Name: Resolver Present Test
Test ID: 3
Test result: Problem detected

CRITERIA
DNS resolver test performs a single DNS query and returns a failing result if a valid response is not returned.
DNS resolver test performs a single DNS query and returns a passing result if a valid response is returned.


DETAILS
Thu Feb 05 2015 00:20:50 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time) - Attempting to resolve hostname: ccd-testing-v4.gstatic.com
Thu Feb 05 2015 00:20:50 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time) - DNS server returned DNS query results.
Thu Feb 05 2015 00:20:50 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time) - DNS server returned problem status code: -105
```

**Windows Troubleshooting**

```
"The default gateway is not available."
```

**I have the following adapter**

```
Intel(R) Centrino(R) Wireless N-2230
```

**Router**

```
AirPort Extreme 802.11n
```

**TCPView**
[image]

**EDIT 1:**
 - OS: Windows 8.1
 - other devices usually stay connected to wifi router at the time when my laptop drops the connection.
 - It looks like it depends on how much data I send to the web. For example, If I work with the cloud, and it often then the connection might drop every 5-10 minutes.
 - The signal is usually good, when it reports "No Internet Access"

Comment: Might want to try a _>netsh winsock reset_ for good measure before you spend money on a new adapter.

Comment: I did just that and restarted my laptop. Is there any definitive test for adapter to confirm that it is defective ?

Answer (score 0):

If it drops connection frequently and/or it doesn't matter how strong is the signal, then it's the adapter.
Recommend replacement.

Comment: With some other connections it has stable connectivity. Can it be some frequency mismatch issue ? Or, timeout issue ?

Comment: Edit your query as you just provided new and question-contradictory information. What other connections? Include also how often connection drops, how far was it from AP and/or what singal strength was at the moment? Do any other devices have same issue? OS installed on laptop?